# How to migrate a Mediawiki installation from Subversion (SVN) to Git

Tags: git, svn, migration, mediawiki

I had Mediawiki installed from Subversion, keeping it up to date with a simple `svn update` command in the installation directory. Mediawiki has now migrated to Git and the latest security updates are only available from there. How to I switch from my Subversion-installation to a git one? Couldn't find any documentation or approach.

Comment: How many locally changed files do you have?  What does `svn stat` say?

Comment: Seven. One changed file, six unversioned.

Comment: You could just back up all 7 files, replace the svn directory with a git non-bare clone, then restore the 7 files.  You only have one file you have to check for conflicts.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, thanks. I've documented my answer but cannot post it due to missing reputation. Will do so after the weekend.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking you should check to see if the unversioned files conflict (MediaWiki could have added a file with the same path to git).  This is unlikely, but you can check with `git status`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do an `svn export` to keep the local changes erase the `.svn` directories, then initialize the exported working copy as a new git project.

```
svn export myproject newproject
cd newproject
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Initializing git repository"
```

Add the Mediawiki git repository to your remote repositories for convenience.

```
git remote add mediawiki https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git
```

Then when you want to do updates, commit your changes and use:

```
git commit -m <your-commit-message-goes-here>
git pull --rebase mediawiki
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to working, but might not be correct or complete. Instructions are not for a production environment (although they worked for me).

1. Create a new directory `httpdocs.new`
2. Lookup the release you want to install, from https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#admin,project,mediawiki/core,branches . At the time of writing `REL1_18` was current stable
3. Clone the desired release of Mediawiki to the new folder, using `git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/core.git --branch REL1_18`
4. Check for local changes in your previous installation `httpdocs`, using e.g. `svn status`
5. Re-do them in the newly created files in `httpdocs.new`. Make file changes, copy files, etc.
6. Rename `httpdocs` to `httpdocs.old`. Your site will be offline.
7. Rename `httpdocs.new` to `httpdocs`. Your new site will be online, but might not work.
8. Run `php maintenance/update.php` to update
9. Check website and amend for errors
   9